# Enviar variables de PHP a JavaScript como parámetros

Tags: javascript, jquery, php7

Estoy intentando que al traer a mi página un módulo (llamado con **jQuery** al archivo principal), me haga una consulta a una base de datos (para modificar los datos). Este último tema, ya lo tengo resuelto, pero hay una cosa especial: Hay 3 `select` que quisiera rellenar con **JavaScript** para darle la opción al usuario de poder seleccionar las otras opciones. Y para mostrar la que seleccionó previamente, pensé en crear una función en **JavaScript**:

```
    function seleccionarCategoria(categoria) {

        var tipo = ['Productos resultados de actividades de generación de nuevo conocimiento', 'Productos resultados de actividades de desarrollo tecnológico e innovación'];

        $("#mostrarTipo").append('<select style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" id="cambiarTipo" name="cambiarTipo" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;"></select>');

        $("#cambiarTipo").append('<option value="">Seleccione un tipo de resultado de investigaci&oacute;n</option>');

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            if (categoria == tipo[i]) {

                $("#cambiarTipo").append('<option value="' + tipo[i] + '" selected>' + tipo[i] + '</option>');

            }else {

                $("#cambiarTipo").append('<option value="' + tipo[i] + '">' + tipo[i] + '</option>');

            }

        }

    }
```

Y luego mostrarlo en el formulario:

```html
    <tr>

        <th><label for="">Categoría a la cuál pertenece:</label></th>

        <td id="mostrarTipo">

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function (e) {

                    seleccionarCategoria(<?php echo $p['tipo_resultado']; ?>);

                });

            </script>

        </td>

    </tr>
```

Pero nada de esto me funciona. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar para poder hacer esto, por favor?

Comment: En tu for loop debería decir i++, le pusiste i-- y se va a ir al infinito

Answer (score 1):

Empezando con la invocación a la función, se espera que mandes una cadena. Por ello, debes mandar tu variable PHP $p entre comillas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    seleccionarCategoria('<?php echo $p['tipo_resultado']; ?>');
  });
</script>
```

Puedes comprobar la misma con un sencillo alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert('<?php echo $p['tipo_resultado']; ?>');
  });
</script>
```

Ahora, para el armado del SELECT te sugiero almacenarlo en variables y adjuntarlos (append) de la siguiente manera:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="">Categoría a la cuál pertenece:</label></th>
  <td id="mostrarTipo"></td>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function seleccionarCategoria(categoria) {
      var tipo = ['Productos resultados de actividades de generación de nuevo conocimiento', 'Productos resultados de actividades de desarrollo tecnológico e innovación'];
      var cambiarTipo = $("<select/>").attr({style:"width: 100%; max-width: 100%;", id:"cambiarTipo", name:"cambiarTipo"});
      cambiarTipo.append('<option value="">Seleccione un tipo de resultado de investigaci&oacute;n</option>');
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i--) {
        var option = $('<option/>');
        if (categoria == tipo[i]) {
          option.attr({'value': tipo[i],'selected':'selected'}).text(tipo[i]);
        } else {
          option.attr({'value':tipo[i]}).text(tipo[i]);
        }
        cambiarTipo.append(option);
      }
      $("#mostrarTipo").append(cambiarTipo);
    }
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
      seleccionarCategoria('<?php echo $p['tipo_resultado']; ?>');
    });
  </script>
</tr>
```